# How boost local_date_time can use time zone database for a given timezone offset?

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

I was trying to understand how Boost::date_time::local_date_time support timezone specific calculations (e.g. : dst etc). I found some information on this link :http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/local_time.html

In the following code, we establish time zone pointer for New York and Phoenix :

```
tz_database tz_db;
tz_db.load_from_file("date_time_zonespec.csv");   
time_zone_ptr nyc_tz = tz_db.time_zone_from_region("America/New_York");
time_zone_ptr phx_tz(new posix_time_zone("MST-07:00:00"));
```

How can we define the time zone ptr for a region for which we have only the time zone offset (for example -7:00:00) and not the name as string (e.g. America/New York)? I need precise calculation of timestamps in various timezones.

Comment: I know it doesn't really answer the question but I don't believe what you're trying is feasible logically. Were you to identify a timezone by feeding in an hour-based offset then when DST hits you're going to get a different result. e.g. if I pass 7 hours now it will return PST (Or PDT) - but if I pass 7 hours in a few months it will return MST.

Comment: @GamerJ5 : Great point. Do you know if boost has a database of timezone abbreviations that it recognizes?

Comment: It requires a csv file that is expected to be created by the developer: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/date_time/tz_db_base.html - couple that with the public-domain TZ database to make what you need: http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm